# How to obtain a reference to the rendered element in the context of a higher-order component?

Tags: reactjs

`Foo` is the higher-order component that wraps `Bar`. I want `Foo` to obtain a reference to the rendered `Bar` element.

```js
import React from 'react';

export default (Bar) => {
    return class Foo extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount = () => {
            // How to obtain reference to the element that Bar renders to?
        }

        render() {
            return <Bar {... this.props} />;
        }
    }
};
```

Trying to obtain a reference to the rendered element using `ref` resolves to an object, which is an instance of the `Bar` as opposed to the element itself:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default (Bar) => {
    return class Foo extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount = () => {
            console.log(this.refs.subject instanceof Bar);
        }

        render() {
            return <Bar ref='subject' {... this.props} />;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `findDOMNode`:

I figured that since `this.refs.bar` is an instance of `Bar`, I can use [`findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.finddomnode) to obtain a reference to the rendered element.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default (Bar) => {
    return class Foo extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount = () => {
            console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.bar));
        };

        render() {
            return <Bar ref='bar' {... this.props} />;
        }
    }
};
```

Previous answer:

The only way I have managed to obtain a reference to the rendered component element is through:

1. Wrapping the `Bar` in a `ReactElement`.
2. Assigning a reference to the `ReactElement`.
3. Iterating the rendered element to obtain its first child node.

```js
import React from 'react';

export default (Bar) => {
    return class Foo extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount = () => {
            console.log(this.refs.bar.firstChild);
        };

        render() {
            return <div ref='bar'>
                <Bar {... this.props} />
            </div>;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting the Bar instance because you're using the arrow function syntax, which inherits `this` from the context in which you declare it. Try using regular function syntax instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.bar));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. `this.refs.bar.firstChild` returns undefined since `this.refs.bar` is an instance of `Bar`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. To get the DOM node you have to use `React.findDOMNode`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the HTML element in React, you can use the `findDOMNode` method, like this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default (Bar) => {
    return class Foo extends React.Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            const subjectEl = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.subject);
        }

        render() {
            return <Bar ref='subject' {... this.props} />;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Beware that `getDOMNode` has been deprecated in React 0.14.0. "Warning: getDOMNode(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Use React.findDOMNode(component) instead."

Answer (score 0):

Using function component:

```
import {useEffect, useRef} from "react";

function Foo() {
    const inputEl = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        inputEl...
    }, [])
    return <Bar ref={inputEl} />
}
```

From: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref